# CentOS 7 won't boot after installing AMDGPU-Pro Driver

Tags: linux, windows, amd-radeon, centos-7

So I recently partitioned my computer to install CentOS 7 in it for project. My original operating system is windows 10, and after partitioning, I could not access windows anymore from the Grub menu.

It got worse. I then tried to install the AMDGPU-Pro driver in the CentOS partition so as to be able to use the graphics card in CentOS 7. The installation went well, and the final step was to reboot the system. I initiated the reboot but it never completed: the system did not reboot. It gets stuck at a screen which shows a white-purple progress bar and a text that reads "centOS Linux 7".

Can anyone help me with this issue? At this point, my computer is essentially unusable. any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you booted into emergency mode and looked at the boot log?

Comment: Hey! so please how do I retrieve the boot log in emergency mode? I am in the emergency mode as root but the path to the AMD folder on the file system is not available. it says "no such file or directory", meaning I cannot even uninstall the driver.

Comment: Follow the instructions here https://computingforgeeks.com/booting-centos-rhel-into-emergency-mode-recovery-mode/ to remount the filesystem as writable. You can then look at the boot log in `/var/log/boot.log`. You can also go into single user mode https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/single-user-mode-in-centos-7-rhel-7.html. Follow the instructions there and you can view the logs and edit files.

Comment: Hi. I can see the boot log, but honestly I am no linux expert. the boot log is a long file and I do not understand what is being said in it. what do you think I should look for please?

Comment: If you're going to use Linux or any other Unix-based OS, then it's important that you understand how to read log files. You want to look for errors. If you need help, then you can paste  the log file here or Google what you see.